# SQL Server varbinary bytes not decoded consistently

Tags: sql-server, varbinary

We have a varbinary field storing some XML data

There is a proc which returns this field to C# calling code which decodes the byte array

```
Encoding.UTF8.GetString((byte[])rdr.GetValue(1))
```

I don't think this is decoding the byte array correctly, and I'm not sure why.

If I copy the varbinary and convert it manually, it doesn't decode correctly:

```
select convert(varchar(max),
0x3C4150495061796D656E7473526......)
```

> Ä•–ÖVçG5&WVW7CàÐ¢Ä†VFW#àÐ¢Å5fW#ã"ããÂõ5fW#àÐ¢Ä6Æ–VçCå

If however I simply convert the column in the proc

```
select convert(varchar(max), filedata), filedata from TABLE
```

It decodes to valid XML.

I can't unfortunately include the actual data. This behaviour is recent and not consistent.

Comment: You did not specify the database collation. is the db collation an UTF8 one ? Otherwise you must apply the COLLATE operotor inside the convert.

Comment: Are you sure you're pasting the correct data and results into your question? The converted data doesn't seem related to the convert statement, it should be displaying `<APIPaymentsR...`

Comment: If the source XML data is only using ASCII code points there will be no difference between `Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes()` and `Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes()`, nor between `Encoding.ASCII.GetString()` and `Encoding.UTF8.GetString()`, because the first 127 code points are a unity transformation in UTF8.

Comment: Curious why you don't store XML in an `xml` column?

Comment: @Charlieface - good question, I'm not sure why.

Comment: @AlwaysLearning - yes thats the issue, the second query does indeed return <APIpaymentsR... . Copying the data into the convert(varchar    statement returns the first result

Comment: Ok, so that begs the question: what are you executing that query from? Just eyeballing the varbinary blob I can see there are no non-ASCII bytes in it so you shouldn't be getting the results that you're getting.

Comment: @AlwaysLearning - I'm running them both in SSMS

Comment: @SQLpro - collation is Latin1_General_CI_AS

Comment: `select convert(varchar(max),0x3C41504979616D656E747352)` returns the correct data so may be there has been a mistake copying the data manually? Is `rdr.GetValue(1)` getting the correct field? What are the first few bytes of the returned byte array?

Comment: @J.R. yes i wondered about that, whether copying the field from SSMS did some truncation. There are well documented issues with copying varchar(max) from SSMS and truncation, I will debug your second question, but it feels like records which don't convert whene manually copied are the same ones that can't be parsed to XML when read directly via the datareader